# Problem when trying to set status using gigya php sdk

Tags: php, javascript, api, sdk, gigya

I am using gigya javascript sdk for authentication purposes on my site. It works well. But I recently decided to try the php sdk, I was able to set status to twitter and linkedin using the php sdk but this I am able to retrieve the uid using the javascript api and when i use to setstatus using php sdk i get an error unauthorised user.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encode uid fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled wall updates in the Gigya site setup page? This is required for using setStatus. Just to be sure, take a quick look at the notes under "Supporting Providers":

http://wiki.gigya.com/030_API_reference/020_REST_API/socialize.setStatus

Comment: I did check it. It works fine on other site and I tried using javascript to setStatus on this site it works fine. I did try to check enable wall updates in the gigya setup page, I could not find the options where you check it. Strange I remember checking it.